# How would I take the value from an input, round it up to the next even number and set that as a new variable

Tags: javascript, html

So I have two text boxes and a single drop-down menu which provide rates. The two text boxes are values given as an inch. I need the inputs to be taken as values, rounded up to the next even number, and then set as a variable. What I have below creates a value which is not a number. What can I do to make that happen as such? Apologies for my

```js
function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  //this takes the
 // values from the inputs, and sets them as a variable
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
  var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
  var result = document.getElementById('result');
  var myBox4 = document.getElementById("myBox1").innerHTML =
    Math.ceil(box1);
  //this line of code
  var myBox5 = document.getElementById("myBox2").innerHTML =
    Math.ceil(box2);
 // and this one, I cannot figure out how to combine given
  //nature above
  var myResult = ((myBox4 * myBox5) / 144) * myBox3;
  result.value = myResult;
  }
```

```html
<td><input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
<td><input id="box2" type="text" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
<td> <select id="box3" oninput="calculate()">
    <option value="8">Clear</option>
    <option value="7">Satin Etched</option>
    <option value="6">Aqualite</option>
    <option value="5">Spraylite</option>
    </select></td>
```

Comment: You're missing myBox and myBox2

Comment: Did my answer below sort your problem? If so, please mark it as the Answer, if not, let me know what else you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the `<td>`s as you haven't supplied the table that they are in.

However, you also need an HTML element for `result`.

Once you get the value from an HTML element and place it in variable, you can work with that variable from then on - no need to get the value again from the element.
So there is no need for `myBox4` and `myBox5`.

You were trying to get the HTML elements `myBox1` and `myBox2` from the page, but they are *variables* that you declared above in javascript.
You were also trying to get `Math.ceil()` for `box1` and `box2` - but these are the `id`s of HTML elements - not javascript variables.

No need for the parenthesis in the calculation because order of precedence has no effect when just multiplying and dividing.

So a working prototype of what you want is:

```
<input id="box1" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
<input id="box2" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />
<select id="box3" oninput="calculate()">
    <option value="8">Clear</option>
    <option value="7">Satin Etched</option>
    <option value="6">Aqualite</option>
    <option value="5">Spraylite</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    function calculate() {
        // Get values from the two inputs, and the dropdown's selected value
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        var rate = document.getElementById('box3').value;

        //Get result element
        var result = document.getElementById('result');

        // Get rounded up values
        var roundedValue01 = Math.ceil(myBox1);
        var roundedValue02 = Math.ceil(myBox2);

        if (roundedValue01 % 2 != 0) {
            roundedValue01 += 1;
        }

        if (roundedValue02 % 2 != 0) {
            roundedValue02 += 1;
        }

        //Calculate and display current amount
        var myResult = roundedValue01 * roundedValue02 / 144 * rate;
        result.textContent = myResult;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know how I would be able to get those numbers rounded up to the next even number? Say for example input 10.5 that turns into 12 and then that is put into the myResult Variable.

Comment: You can check the value using modulo: roundedValue01 % 2. I've added this to the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Step by step, you want to:

1. Get value 1 from the DOM, rounded up.
2. Get value 2 from the DOM, rounded up.
3. Add the two values together.
4. Set the resulting value in an element in the DOM.

Here is what you can do:

```
function calculate() {
 var value1 = Math.ceil(document.getElementById('box1').value);
 var value2 = Math.ceil(document.getElementById('box2').value);
 var addedValues = value1 + value2;
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = addedValues;
}
```

With this code, you must have two inputs, with `id="box1"` and `id="box2"` and you must also have an element with `id="result"` to show the result.

Comment: Thank you So much
     var value1 = Math.ceil(document.getElementById('box1').value);
     var value2 = Math.ceil(document.getElementById('box2').value);
is exactly what I was looking for!